# Load test increasing CPU utilization and server stops responding

Tags: tomcat, jmeter, google-cloud-platform

I have a java application which is running in Tomcat server. I was trying to load test of my application with Jmeter. While I put a load of more than 100 users, the CPU utilization increases drastically and also the server becomes unresponsive. I have an option to restrict with tomcat tunning. How to prevent, In case there is an intentional unauthorized load test on the server?

Comment: `I have an option to restrict with tomcat tunning.` What does that mean? Set your maximum allowed number of concurrently active sessions to 10. Every additional user will then get a quick exception instead of invoking your business logic.

Comment: You might also want to increase Tomcat available heap space or tweak your application performance plus reduce the amount of memeory used per user session.